# Should I include the binary in a rubygem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, binaryfiles

I am making a rubygem and the binary library I need to call is found in a folder under a user-determined directory. Due to this, should I include this 6MB file into my rubygem's **bin** directory or is there a better approach to this?

Currently I am doing this for osx. If I want to port this to windows, I wil have the same issue and the binary file will also be of a different file type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the library available form other sources? If not: Include it, because you need it and it is required.

If the library may be available: Why not create two (or more) gems?
See for example [rmagick](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rmagick). There is a standard gem and a win32-specific binary gem.

Disclaimer: If it is not your own binary: Please check the license of the binary before you add it (this belongs not only for binaries, but to all stuff you add to your gem)

Comment: You might also list the library in the gem's requirements, see http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#requirements.